# citation in square brackets

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

I am preparing a paper to submit it for a journal using their template. When I cite a reference (natbib package) using \cite it appears as "authors (year)", using \citep it appears "(authors year)"...

Is there a way to cite a reference and to obtain "[authors year]" ?

(the template source is available in overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/taylor-and-francis-latex-template-for-authors-interact-layout-plus-chicago-reference-style/jfkyqxkxqhrs)

Comment: Why would you even want to do that? Isn't the point of using “their” template to follow their style guidelines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: a]

Using `\bibpunct[, ]{[}{]}{;}{a}{}{,}` => citation support using `natbib.sty`

```
\documentclass[]{interact}

\usepackage{natbib}% Citation support using natbib.sty

\bibpunct[, ]{[}{]}{;}{a}{}{,}% Citation support using natbib.sty % CHANGED <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\renewcommand\bibfont{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}% Bibliography support using natbib.sty

\begin{document}

\title{Taylor \& Francis \LaTeX\ template for authors (\textsf{Interact} layout + [author-date] reference style)}

\maketitle

\section{References}

\begin{itemize}
    
    \item One author \verb|\citep{Fow89}| \citep{Fow89}
    
    \item One author \verb|\cite{Fow89}| \cite{Fow89}
    
    \item Two or more authors  \verb|\citep{Bro86,Bro02,Roh08} |  \citep{Bro86,Bro02,Roh08} 
    
    \item Two or more authors  \verb|\cite{Bro86,Bro02,Roh08} |  \cite{Bro86,Bro02,Roh08} 

\end{itemize}   
    
\begin{thebibliography}{}


\bibitem[Brooks and McLennan(2002)]{Bro02}
Brooks, Daniel~R., and Deborah~A. McLennan. 2002. \emph{The Nature of
 Diversity: An Evolutionary Voyage of Discovery}. Chicago: University of
 Chicago Press.

\bibitem[Brooks and Wiley(1986)]{Bro86}
Brooks, Daniel~R., and E.~O. Wiley. 1986. \emph{Evolution as Entropy}. 2nd ed.
 Chicago: University of Chicago Press.

\bibitem[Fowler(1989)]{Fow89}
Fowler, Melvin~L. 1989. \emph{The Cahokia Atlas: A Historical Atlas of Cahokia
 Archaeology}. Studies in Illinois Archaeology~6. Springfield: Illinois
 Historic Preservation Agency.

\bibitem[Rohde, Levy, and Kehler(2008)]{Roh08}
Rohde, Hannah, Roger Levy, and Andrew Kehler. 2008. ``Implicit Causality Biases
 Influence Relative Clause Attachment.'' Poster presented at the 21st CUNY
 Conference on Human Sentence Processing, Chapel Hill, NC, March.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```